# Querying a list of jobs on a server using EJBs

Tags: java, thread-safety

Inspired by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/18578/8953), I have a Java Enterprise application running in Glassfish 2.1 and a Java SE client that communicates with the server application.

For this I have a bean that maintains a collection of jobs that is set by the server and the client then asks if his job is in the current list of jobs known to the bean.

I want to ask if this code is good.

The client uses this interface:

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
public interface GeneratorCancelledRemote {
    public boolean isJobCancelled(String jobId);
}
```

The server uses this interface:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.ejb.Local;
@Local
public interface GeneratorCancelledLocal {
    public void setJobs(final Collection<String> jobs);
}
```

And here's the implementation:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless
public class GeneratorCancelled implements GeneratorCancelledLocal, GeneratorCancelledRemote {
    private Collection<String>  jobs;
    public void setJobs(final Collection<String> jobs) {
        this.jobs = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
        this.jobs.addAll(jobs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isJobCancelled(final String jobId) {
        return jobs != null && jobs.contains(jobId);
    }
}
```

Obviously access to the collection of jobs has to be synchronized somehow. Is the use of `Collections.synchronizedSet` the best way to do this? The EJB gurus around here shun on the use of `synchronized` in an EE context.

I found [this](http://blog.holisticon.de/2010/11/synchronisation-und-nebenlaufigkeitskontrolle-mit-ejbs-leicht-gemacht/) (in German), which also explains that `synchronized` is not allowed in EJB.

Comment: I don't know much about EJB, but the article looks horrible to me. I know quite a lot about concurrency in Java SE, and after reading the article I still don't know anything about concurrency in Java EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `@Stateless` service contains a shared state. It looks weird for me.
2. You never modify a state of `jobs`, you always create a new object

   ```
   this.jobs = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
   ```

   Could you please clarify why ?
3. From synchronization standpoint you have a race condition in `setJobs` method, so it should be `synchronized`.
4. Now, since your write operation (`setJobs` method) is protected by the intrinsic lock, all read operations should be also protected by the same lock to ensure data visibility. Make `isJobCancelled` synchronized too.

Comment: 2: `Collections.synchronizedSet` does not create a new object (the collection is not cloned), only a view. 3&4: As I say, the EJB-gurus here balk on the use of synchronized in beans.

Comment: Of course `Collections.synchronizedSet` does not create a new object. I'm talking about **new HashSet<String>()**.

Comment: Actually, `Collections.synchronizedSet` does create a new tiny object, but I see what you mean. The thing with `new HashSet<String>()` is defensive copy. Here, it's needed to ensure the stored collection doesn't change sneakily. It's strictly necessary here: If you work on a provided collection to which someone has unlimited unsynchronized access, then any synchronization is futile.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the use of Collections.synchronizedSet the best way to do this?

No way. It allows you to do some operations atomically, e.g., `addAll`, but what you'd need is to replace the whole content by e.g. `clear` and `addAll` executed atomically *together*.

But there's a simple way to get rid of your race condition:

```
public void setJobs(final Collection<String> jobs) {
    Collection<String> copy = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
    copy.addAll(jobs);
    this.jobs = copy;
}
```

As long as you keep you collection private to the method, there can be no race.

However, it's still wrong, namely because of the second bug. If one thread writes `jobs`, there's no guarantee that another one sees the new value. It may see the old value for an indefinite amount of time.

To the rescue, you could declare `jobs` as `volatile`. Or use an `AtomicReference` or whatever.

Then it works, however, there are no operation on your set which would need it to be synchronized. The only writing happens to a local variable constrained to a single thread, the safe publication happens via `volatile`, and `contains` is reading only of an effectively immutable object and needs no synchronization.

*So there's no use for `Collections.synchronizedSet` here. Anyway, I strongly suggest to use the `synchronized` keyword (or equivalents provided by EJB) as it's the least error prone way. Note that even in these few lines there were two serious bugs. And debugging it is a real pain as it's all inherently non-deterministic.*